# Problem with circuit composer results tab

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I'm trying to run a simulation of the following circuit:

[image]

on the ibmq_qasm_simulator, but it only shows the "Circuit diagram" without the "Circuit Implementation" and "Results tab".
Did someone had that problem before ?

*Note: Ever since it happened, every simulation I ran before started to have this problem too.*

Comment: Hi, I think this is because the simulator can run the circuit without the need for transpilation. Do you mean you can't see any results?

Comment: Yes, usually in the results tab , that you can open after running a simulation there are results of measured values. It doesn't show that any more, even in circuits i already had seen the results before.

Comment: I am experiencing same problem. Only circuit is shown but histogram with results is not. Can anybody from IBM check this? Seems as a platform error.

Comment: This is a known problem which, according to a message on the Qiskit Slack is expected to be fixed on Monday.

Comment: Got fixed , thanks for the help guys :)